# PostgreSQL installation failed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I recently uninstalled postgresql from my computer. I tried to install it again but I faced some problems. I tried to fully uninstall it again like this:
I found al the packages related to postgres:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

Them I removed all the packages and related folders :

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.3

$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/
$ sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
```

I've tried to install it again, but after the installation I can't access postgres user.

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
$ sudo -i -u postgres
sudo: unable to change directory to /home/postgres: No such file or directory
```

If I access root I can access postgres but this is what happens:

```
$ sudo su -
$ su - postgres
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
postgres@rafael-pc:/$ psql
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \q
could not save history to file "/home/postgres/.psql_history": No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what is happening. I've tried to uninstall it many times but I always have some kind of error when I install it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess here, but it sure looks to me like the problem is that there isn't a `/home/postgres` directory. I'm not sure what may have happened in your uninstall process to remove that, but it looks like that's the cause of the error in both of the steps you list.

Can you try this (or some approximation of these steps, which create that directory and make sure it's owned by the postgres user)?

```
# sudo mkdir /home/postgres
# sudo chown postgres /home/postgres
```